# Deploy Angular 2 app to Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, typescript, angular

When I run my index.html file in my (typescript) Angular 2 app which is also a Parse.com app (It has the cloud and public, parse.local and parse.project directories etc) it runs fine. But when I try to deploy it to Parse.com it doesn't deploy.

A lot of errors show in the terminal saying Bad file name for the files in the node_modules folder.

Is my node modules folder in the wrong directory? Or do I need to get rid of all of the files that have a bad file name according to parse.com?

Here is my project file structure:

[image]

Here is a sample of the error log in the terminal after typing parse deploy from the root directory of my project - The actual error log is too big to paste the whole thing. Notice that it says

> Open file xxx - too many open files
>
> open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/define-property.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/event-target.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/file-reader.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/functions.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/geolocation.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/mutation-observer.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/promise.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/property-descriptor.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/register-element.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/patch/websocket.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/utils.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zones/long-stack-trace.js:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/node_modules/zone.js/package.json:
>   too many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/package.json: too
>   many open files | open
>   /Users/Ben/development/whatwegrowangular2/public/tsconfig.json: too
>   many open files

Here is another sample of a different error from the same terminal:

> Bad file name:
>
> > node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/balanced-match/package.json
> >     | Bad file name:
> >     node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/balanced-match/test/balanced.js
> >     | Bad file name:
> >     node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/concat-map/README.markdown
> >     | Bad file name:
> >     node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/concat-map/example/map.js
> >     | Bad file name:
> >     node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/concat-map/package.json
> >     | Bad file name:
> >     node_modules/fsevents/node_modules/rimraf/node_modules/glob/node_modules/minimatch/node_modules/brace-expansion/node_modules/concat-map/test/map.js
> >     | Bad file name:
> >     node_modules/ua-parser-js/test/browser&mediaplayer-test.json Will
> >     retry in 1 seconds

**EDIT: I moved the node modules that were actually used out of the node_modules folder and deleted the node_modules folder. The index.html file still runs and looks fine. But when I try to deploy to parse.com, I get this error now:**

> Finished uploading files Deploy failed with error: You have 3029
>   hosted files but are limited to 500 Will retry in 0 seconds.

Comment: You should add the error messages you're getting.

Comment: @EricMartinez Have done that now. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to load all node_modules via a CDN script tag in my html file, not by having the actual node_module files in my project.

At this stage I have these two script tags and it kinda works (All that is on the page is an angular 2 component which has a bootstrap danger button - It works fine it just loads kinda slow):

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.47/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system-csp-production.js"></script>
```

I get these errors in the console:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined bootstrap.min.js:6
>   Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery bundle.js:27364
>   Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to
>   enable the production mode. angular2.dev.js:138
>   http://whatwegrowangular2.parseapp.com/app/bundle.js did not call
>   System.register or AMD define     Error loading
>   http://whatwegrowangular2.parseapp.com/app/bundle.js

Please comment with any other cdn script tags to include in my index.html file to get rid of all errors. Thanks.

Here is my full index.html file:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart</title>
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-alpha.47/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.18.4/system-csp-production.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    <script>
      System.config({
        packages: {        
          app: {
            format: 'register',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
          }
        }
      });
      System.import('app/bundle')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 3. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```